# Difference between Powershell ISE and PowerGUI for [Environment+SpecialFolder]

Tags: powershell, powergui

I'm making a powershell installation script for an app at work and I'm constantly switching from PowerShell ISE to PowerGUI to make it.

I found a difference between them I really can't explain and I'd like to have some advice.

For the same following code :

```
$test = ""
$feedback = $FALSE
try
{
    $test = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ProgramFilesX86)
}
catch
{
    $test = ""
}
if($test -eq "")
{
    $feedback = $TRUE
}
else
{
    $feedback = $FALSE
}
"Feedback : " + $feedback
"Result : " + $test
```

Powershell ISE returns :

```
Feedback : True
Result :
```

And PowerGUI returns :

```
Feedback : False
Result : C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Of course, C:\Program Files (x86) is an existing folder.

I'm curious to understand why.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environments are not playing the same version of PowerShell, or at least the same version of the the CLR. try to look at `$PSVersionTable`.

Environment.SpecialFolder enum contains `ProgramFilesX86` in NET Framework 4.5  this was not the case in NET Framework 3.5 and previous versions.